# 広範な規約に関する質問について

Tags: 討議

通報してみたのですが却下され、質問自体もプラス票になっていたのでこちらで質問します。

[クラスファイルの書き換えが何らかの規約に抵触することはありますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/26766/%E3%82%AF%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B9%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8D%E6%8F%9B%E3%81%88%E3%81%8C%E4%BD%95%E3%82%89%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AE%E8%A6%8F%E7%B4%84%E3%81%AB%E6%8A%B5%E8%A7%A6%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B)

> 質問ですが、自作のコードをコンパイルして生成したクラスファイルの書き換えを行ったり、書き換えたクラスファイルをVMに読み込ませたり、配布したりすることが（例えばコンパイラ提供者の）規約に抵触するということはあるでしょうか？

上記質問において、質問者が想定している利用法に関係すると思われる規約は
以下のようになると思います。

・コンパイラの規約
・自作のコードの規約、ライブラリ等を使用していればその規約
・VMの規約
・配布場所の規約

このうち「配布場所の規約」などは無数に存在し、悪魔の証明的で「ないとはいえない」
としか答えられないかと思います。

この質問はどのような回答が期待され、有効となっているのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

その質問に関して言えば、

> （例えばコンパイラ提供者の）

と書かれていますから、JDKのEULA上問題ないのかということについて述べたうえで、他にどこに注意すべきなのか、といった形で回答できるのかなと思いました。

また、人によって答えがバラバラで解が収束しない質問はオフトピックだとしても、「答えなどない」という解に収束するなら、それを回答として投稿すればいいのではないでしょうか。何に気をつければいいのかわからない、というか思いもよらぬところで制限があった、というのはよくある話ですから、そういったヒントがあるだけでも役立つでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

この具体的な質問に絞った、自分の意見を書きます。

多分、質問者、ないし upvote した人にとって、「ないとはいえない」ことが、わからないのだと思います。具体的にこの場で列挙していただいた事項のように、さまざま関わってくる規約があることを知らない(よくわかっていない)のだと思います。

なので、ここに記述してもらったことを回答として投稿するのがいいのではないか、と思っています。